# How do I split a string at the first space and consign the strings to different variables?

Tags: c, string, spaces

I need to find a way to split a two word string at the space in the middle.

I then need to consign the two new strings into two variables (x and y).

I would prefer the second string to start at the position of the next letter after the space.

I'm new at this so any simple advice would be welcome.

Comment: Have a look at `strtok`. Should be all you need.

Comment: I don't know how to use strtok to allocate the 2 strings into new arrays. I'm new to all this so more info is needed.

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there on how to use `strtok`. Give it a try. Post your attempt at using `strtok` if you get stuck.

Comment: strtok has nothing to do with allocation. The fact you are a novice doesn't excuse you from doing research. I gave you a hint, and if you expect to be spoon fed, you are in for a dissapointment

Comment: what do you mean by "consign"? A simple google search will give you tons of solutions, have you tried it? Without showing what you have tried soon your question will be closed on SO

Comment: The word 'consign' means to 'allocate'. It's not a computer term.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) function in order to find the first occurrence of `' '` in the string. You can then do something like this:

```
char* wholeSentence = "hello world";
char* startOfSecond = strchr(wholeSentence, ' '); // " world";
size_t lengthOfFirst = startOfSecond - wholeSentence;
char* first = (char*)malloc((lengthOfFirst + 1) * sizeof(char));
strncpy(first, wholeSentence, lengthOfFirst)); // "hello"
```

You can find out the second in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

use **strtok**
*Example:*

```
 char x[80] = "This is";
 const char s[] = " ";
 char *y;
 strtok(x, s); // first string
 y = strtok(NULL, s); // second string
```